# Creating an timed circular progressbar using java

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am new in programming and I am exploring android studio. I wanted to make a workout timer that uses a timed circular progress bar. There is a kotlin tutorial on youtube but I am not familiar with it. I wanted to make the progressbar looped to other progress bar. for example after 30 seconds of workout another progressbar will show 10 seconds of rest, after that another 30s will be shown to the progress bar. I can't start yet because I have minimal knowledge of how progressbar works. can someone show me where to start to make my sample app?

Comment: oh sorry I thought I can have some help here. I just wanted to know on what should I know first in creating timed progressbar. not the whole tutorial.

Comment: Have you read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Progress Bar for example?

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I think I know where to start. never thought of visiting the site.